# Set permissions/authentication for spring-cloud-stream message consumer so it passes @PreAuthorize checks

Tags: spring-boot, authentication, spring-security, google-cloud-pubsub, spring-cloud-stream

I consume messages from `spring-cloud-stream` through a `Consumer<MyMessage>` Implementation. As part of the message handling I need to access methods that are protected with `@PreAuthorize` security-checks. By default the `Consumer` run unauthenticated so message-handling fails.

Consumer:

```
@Bean
public Consumer<MyMessage> exampleMessageConsumer(MyMessageConsumer consumer) {
    return consumer::handleMessage;
}
```

Secured Method:

```
@PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('ROLE_ADMIN') or hasAuthority('ROLE_USER')")
public void doSomething() { ... }
```

I dont just want to bypass security, so what is the easiest way to authenticate my Consumer so it passes the check?

**EDIT:** we are using google pubsub as a binder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found two possible solutions to my problem

1. use springs `RunAs` support ([baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-run-as-auth)) to add permissions to a security context for a specific method. If i do this i need to add `ROLE_RUN_AS_USER` to my secured methods. At scale this would complicated annotations a lot.
2. Manually change the security context before executing the handler method and return it to its original state afterwards.

I went with the second option. I would have liked a transparent solution but there does not appear to be one.

To make this work i created a class that wraps a functional interface with the changing code and returns it.

```
public class RunAs {

    @FunctionalInterface
    public interface RunAsMethod {
        void runWithException() throws Throwable;
    }

    public static <T> Consumer<T> createWriteConsumer(Consumer<T> originalConsumer) {
        return message -> runWithWritePermission(() -> originalConsumer.accept(message));
    }

    public static void runWithWritePermission(final RunAsMethod func) {
        final Authentication originalAuthentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();

        final AnonymousAuthenticationToken token = new AnonymousAuthenticationToken(
            "system",
            originalAuthentication != null ? originalAuthentication.getPrincipal() : "system",
            AuthorityUtils.createAuthorityList("ROLE_ADMIN", "SCOPE_write")
        );

        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(token);
        try {
            func.runWithException();
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("exception during method with altered permissions", e);
        } finally {
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(originalAuthentication);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For the Kafka binder:

Add an `@EventListener` to listen for `ConsumerStartedEvent`s; you can then add the authentication to the security context via the `SecurityContextHolder`; this binds it to the thread; the same thread is used to call the listener.

Comment: that appears to be a kafka only thing, so thats out as we don't use kafka

Comment: You should have said which binder(s) you are using; there may be a solution for other binders.

Comment: edited my question. we are using google pubsub.

Comment: I am not familiar with that binder or if it supports events; worse case is you can set up the security context in your `Consumer<?>` before calling `MyMessageConsumer. handleMessage()`.